# Movie rent terminal application

Tags: java, object-oriented

[Part 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/171533/movie-rent-terminal-application-rev3)

I'm studying Java (as a hobby) and decided to create a little simple app just to see what I've learned. The app's purpose is to store data about movie rents: who, what movie, movie's price, check out date, return date, and if the rent is overdue - overdue fee. I know the app is useless in real world but I thought it would be a good idea for studying purpose. I would be very glad if somebody took a look at the code and helped me point out errors, bad practices, etc.

**Main.java**

```
package graykas;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Menu.showMainMenu();
    }
}
```

**Movie.java**

```
package graykas;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
public class Movie
{
    private String movieTitle;
    private BigDecimal rentPrice;

    public Movie(String movieTitle, double rentPrice)
    {
        this.movieTitle = movieTitle;
        this.rentPrice = new BigDecimal(rentPrice);
    }

    public String getMovieTitle() {   return movieTitle;    }
    //public void setMovieTitle(String movieTitle) {  this.movieTitle = movieTitle;   }
    public BigDecimal getRentPrice() { return rentPrice.add(BigDecimal.ZERO);   }
    //public void setRentPrice(int rentPrice) {   this.rentPrice = rentPrice; }
}
```

**Rent.java**

```
package graykas;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
public class Rent
{
    //Overdue fee per day in dollars
    public static final BigDecimal OVERDUE_FEE = new BigDecimal(5);

    private String clientName;
    private Movie movie;
    private LocalDate checkoutDate;
    private LocalDate returnDate;
    private BigDecimal overdueFee;

    public Rent(String clientName, Movie movie, String returnDateString) throws IOException, NullPointerException
    {
        setClientName(clientName);
        setMovie(movie);
        setCheckoutDate(LocalDate.now());

        try {   setReturnDate(returnDateString);  }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(
                    String.format("Error converting returnDate from String to LocalDate: %s. Using current date instead!", ex.getMessage()));
            setReturnDate(this.checkoutDate);
        }

        updateOverdueFee();
    }

    /**
     * Updates overdueFee if currentDate > returnDate per formula: (currentDate - returnDate) * OVERDUE_FEE
     * Or sets overdueFee to 0, if it is not initialized yet
     */
    public void updateOverdueFee()
    {
        if(LocalDate.now().isAfter(returnDate))
        {
            overdueFee = BigDecimal.valueOf(Period.between(returnDate, LocalDate.now()).getDays());
            overdueFee = overdueFee.multiply(OVERDUE_FEE);
        }
        else if(overdueFee == null) overdueFee = new BigDecimal(0);
    }

    public String getClientName() { return clientName;  }
    public void setClientName(String clientName) throws IOException
    {
        if ("".equals(clientName)) throw new IOException("Name can't be empty or null!");
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }

    //public Movie getMovie() {   return movie;   }
    private void setMovie(Movie movie) throws NullPointerException
    {
        if (movie == null) throw new NullPointerException("Movie object can't be null!");
        this.movie = movie;
    }

    //public LocalDate getCheckoutDate() {    return checkoutDate;    }
    private void setCheckoutDate(LocalDate checkoutDate) {   this.checkoutDate = checkoutDate;   }

    //public LocalDate getReturnDate() {  return returnDate;  }
    private void setReturnDate(LocalDate returnDate) {   this.returnDate = returnDate;   }

    /**
     * Converts returnDateString to returnDate LocalDate object
     * @param returnDateString - returnDate represented as String
     * @throws IOException if returnDateString is empty or null
     * @throws DateTimeParseException if returnDateString is not using formula yyyy-MM-dd
     */
    private void setReturnDate(String returnDateString) throws IOException, DateTimeParseException {
        //Checks for string's emptiness. If fails -> throws IOException
        //if(returnDateString == null || returnDateString.isEmpty()) throw new IOException("The return date is empty or null");
        if("".equals(returnDateString)) throw new IOException("The return date is empty or null");

        //Tries to parse the string. If fails -> throws DateTimeParseException
        this.returnDate = LocalDate.parse(returnDateString);
    }

    public BigDecimal getOverdueFee()
    {
        return overdueFee.add(BigDecimal.ZERO);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        /*
        Output example:
            Name: Jack
            Movie title: Harry Potter
            Rent price: $20.99
            Checkout date: 2017-07-28
            Return date: 2017-08-05
            Overdue fee: $0.00
        */
        NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        //noinspection StringBufferReplaceableByString
        StringBuilder strBld = new StringBuilder();
        strBld.append("Name: ").append(clientName).append("\n");
        strBld.append("Movie title: ").append(movie.getMovieTitle()).append("\n");
        strBld.append("Rent price: ").append(currencyFormat.format(movie.getRentPrice())).append("\n");
        strBld.append("Checkout date: ").append(checkoutDate).append("\n");
        strBld.append("Return date: ").append(returnDate).append("\n");
        strBld.append("Overdue fee: ").append(currencyFormat.format(overdueFee));

        return strBld.toString();
    }
}
```

**Database.java**

```
package graykas;

import com.sun.istack.internal.Nullable;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
public class Database
{
    private static final String[] randomNames = {"John", "Felicia", "Ivan", "Boris", "Kristina", "Elena", "Vladimir", "Jane", "Maxim"};
    private static final String[] randomMovieTitles = {"Twilight", "Deadpool", "Big Hero 6", "Harry Potter"};
    private static final String[] randomReturnDates = {"2017-07-21", "2017-07-25", "2017-08-01", "2017-07-01", "2018-07-21"};

    private final List<Rent> database = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Returns a Rent object from a specified index
     * @param index - position in the List
     * @return the desired Rent object
     */
    @Nullable
    public Rent get(int index)
    {
        if(database.size() < index) return null;
        return database.get(index);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a clone of the database
     * @return cloned db
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Rent> getClone()
    {
        return (List<Rent>) ((ArrayList<Rent>) database).clone();
    }

    /**
     * Adds item to the database
     * @param item - the Rent object to add
     * @return the index of the added object(-1 if there was an error)
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedReturnValue")
    public int add(Rent item)
    {
        if(item == null)
        {
            System.err.println("Error adding a Rent object to the database: A null Rent object can't be added to the database!");
            return -1;
        }
        database.add(item);
        return database.lastIndexOf(item);
    }

    /**
     * Replaces the Rent object at a specified index with a new one
     * @param index - index in the database of the Rent object to replace
     * @param item - Rent object to replace to
     */
    public void set(int index, Rent item)
    {
        if(item == null)
        {
            System.err.println("Error adding a Rent object to the database: A null Rent object can't be added to the database!");
            return;
        }
        database.set(index, item);
    }

    /**
     * Is the db empty?
     * @return true if empty
     *         false if not
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {  return database.isEmpty();  }

    /**
     * @return size of the database
     */
    public int size() { return database.size();  }

    /**
     * Inserts x-amount random objects into the db
     */
    public void generateRandomData(int amount)
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
                database.add(new Rent(
                        randomNames[(int) (Math.random() * 100) % randomNames.length],
                        new Movie(
                                randomMovieTitles[(int) (Math.random() * 100) % randomMovieTitles.length],
                                (int) (Math.random() * 10) % 50 + 25),
                        randomReturnDates[(int) (Math.random() * 100) % randomReturnDates.length]));
        }
        catch (IOException | NullPointerException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Error adding random data to the database: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Menu.java**

```
package graykas;

import com.sun.istack.internal.Nullable;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Scanner;

@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
public class Menu
{
    private static final Database database = new Database();

    //Scanner object to get input from the terminal
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     * Shows main menu options
     */
    public static void showMainMenu()
    {
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Available options:");
            System.out.println("1 - List all rents");
            System.out.println("2 - List only overdue rents");
            System.out.println("3 - Add a new rent");
            System.out.println("4 - Edit an existing rent");
            System.out.println("5 - Generate random data");
            System.out.println("0 - Exit");
            System.out.print("Choice -> ");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();

            switch (input)
            {
                case "1":
                    listAllRents();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    listOverdueRents();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    addRentObjectLoop();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    editExistingRentObject();
                    break;
                case "5":
                    database.generateRandomData(5);
                    break;
                case "0":
                    scanner.close();
                    return;
            }
        } while(true);
    }

    /**
     * Lists all the rent objects from the database
     */
    public static void listAllRents()
    {
        //If database is empty -> show "The database is empty" message, else list all the Rent objects' values
        if(!database.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
            for (Rent rent : database.getClone())
            {
                System.out.println(rent);
                System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
            }
        }
        else System.out.println("The database is empty");
    }

    /**
     * Lists all the Rent objects from the database when overdueFee > 0
     */
    private static void listOverdueRents()
    {
        //If database is empty -> show "The database is empty" message, else list all the Rent objects' values when overdueFee > 0
        if(!database.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
            for (Rent rent : database.getClone())
            {
                if(rent.getOverdueFee().compareTo(new BigDecimal(0)) > 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(rent);
                    System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
                }
            }
        }
        else System.out.println("The database is empty");
    }

    /**
     * Gets Rent objects from user in a loop
     */
    public static void addRentObjectLoop()
    {
        do
        {
            //Gets values for a new Rent object from the user and adds it ti the database
            database.add(getRentObjectFieldsInput());

            //If user doesn't want to continue -> break
            if(!addRentObjectMessage()) break;
        } while(true);
    }

    /**
     * Displays "Do you want to continue?" message
     * @return boolean - true if the user wants to add a new Rent object
     *                  false if does not
     */
    public static boolean addRentObjectMessage()
    {
        System.out.print("Add a new rent? ->");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        switch (input)
        {
            case "y":
            case "Y":
            case "1":
                return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    /**
     * Gets input for a new Rent object
     * @return Rent object with the data from user
     */
    @Nullable
    public static Rent getRentObjectFieldsInput()
    {
        String clientName;
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Client name -> ");
            clientName = scanner.nextLine();

            if(!"".equals(clientName)) break;
            System.err.println("Name can't be empty or null! Please, try again");
        } while(true);

        String movieTitle;
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Movie title -> ");
            movieTitle = scanner.nextLine();

            if(!"".equals(movieTitle)) break;
            System.err.println("Movie title can't be empty or null! Please, try again");
        } while(true);

        //noinspection UnusedAssignment
        double rentPrice = -1;
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Rent price -> ");
            rentPrice = scanner.nextDouble();
            scanner.nextLine();

            if(rentPrice != -1) break;
            System.err.println("Rent price can't be empty or null! Please, try again");
        } while(true);

        String returnDate;
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Return date -> ");
            returnDate = scanner.nextLine();

            if(!"".equals(returnDate)) break;
            System.err.println("Return date can't be empty or null! Please, try again");
        } while(true);

        try
        {
            return new Rent(clientName, new Movie(movieTitle, rentPrice), returnDate);
        }
        catch (IOException | NullPointerException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Error creating a Rent object: " + ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds an existing Rent object with the client name specified by the user, shows all its parameters and gets new values
     */
    public static void editExistingRentObject()
    {
        //listAllRents();
        System.out.print("Enter the client name who's rent to edit -> ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();

        Rent toEdit = null;
        int counter;
        for (counter = 0; counter < database.size(); counter++)
        {
            if(name.equals(database.get(counter).getClientName()))
            {
                toEdit = database.get(counter);
                break;
            }
        }

        if(toEdit == null)
        {
            System.out.println("The rent with the specified client name was not found");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println(toEdit);
        database.set(counter, getRentObjectFieldsInput());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to put this question on hold temporarily while I figure out what to do with this questions, as some of your updates have already been answered in an answer. This is probably not permanently.

Comment: Both question and answer has been rollbacked. The edit history can still be seen. If you want a review of the latest code, I'd recommend that you post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are storing the price of a movie in `Movie.java` as a `BigDecimal`, which you create using the constructor `BigDecimal(double)`. This almost certainly doesn't do what you probably think it does. You think `new BigDecimal(19.99)` creates a `BigDecimal` that represents *exactly* `19.99`? Wrong. It actually represents `19.989999999999998436805981327779591083526611328125`. For an explanation why, I recommend you read [the description of said constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-). To create a `BigDecimal` that really represents *exactly* `19.99`, you need to do it via the `static` factory method `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`. Also, what's the purpose of calling `add(BigDecimal.ZERO)` before returning the rent price?

Anyway, using a `BigDecimal` for the price of a movie really seems overkill. `BigDecimal`s are objects as opposed to primitive types like `int` and `double`, and thus carry with them overhead and are slower and also less flexible, because you cannot use operators like `+`, `-`, `*` etc. with them as you can with primitive types. If you are intent on precision, which is in no way wrong, you can just store the price of a movie in cents. That way, you can store it as an `int` and you don't have to worry about precision.

On to `Rent.java`. You are misusing the class `IOException`. Looking at the subclasses of [`IOException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) might give you an idea what an `IOException` is for. For example, trying to read from a file that doesn't exist would throw an `IOException`. A connection attempt to a server timing out is another use case for `IOException`. But passing a parameter to a method is not an I/O-operation. What you want is an `IllegalArgumentException`. Note that `IllegalArgumentException` (as well as `NullPointerException`) is a subclass of `RuntimeException`, which means that you don't need to declare that a method might throw it (you can still add a `@throws` tag to the javadoc even if you don't explicitly specify a `RuntimeException` in the method declaration).

You seem to be under the impression that `if ("".equals(someString))` is a shortcut for `if (someString == null || someString.isEmpty())`. Why would you think that? If `someString` is `null`, then `if ("".equals(someString))` will return `false`. An empty `String` is not the same as `null`. If you think it is, you have misunderstood the concept of `null`.

By the way, there is a shortcut for checking whether an object is `null`: `<T> Objects.requireNonNull(T)`, or alternatively, with an error message, `<T> Objects.requireNonNull(T, String)`. It will even return the passed object if it is non-`null`, so you could just do this in the `Rent` constructor, eliminating the need for a `private` helper method:

```java
this.movie = Objects.requireNonNull(movie, "Movie object can't be null!");
```

In the method `setReturnDate(String)`, the manual (and faulty – see above) check for `null` or an empty string is redundant, because `LocalDate.parse(CharSequence)` will throw a `DateTimeParseException` anyway (which, by the way, is also a `RuntimeException`, so you don't need to specify it) if the `String` is malformed, or a `NullPointerException` if it is `null`. And with just this one line, you might as well skip the method `setReturnDate(String)` and just directly initialize `returnDate` in the constructor. Also, you should replace `catch (Exception ex)` with `catch (NullPointerException | DateTimeParseException ex)` (note that you can catch multiple exceptions), because you are only expecting these two exceptions. If there is a bug in your program, or if for any other reason another exception is thrown against your expecation, you will never know, and the bug will remain undetected.

You are calling an overridable method (`updateOverdueFee()`) from the constructor. [This is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348797/why-is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-call-a-method-from-within-a-constructor). Also, I think you inadvertently made `setClientName(String)` `public`, while it should probably be `private'.

`Database.get(int)`: The index of a `List` is zero-based, so you need `<=` instead of `<` in the comparison. Also, did you consider that `index` might be negative? Throwing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` (which is what `List.get(int)` will do if the index is out of bounds) instead of returning a useless `null` would be fail-fast, meaning a potential bug can be caught as early as possible and as close to its source as possible. Unless you have a specific reason for returning `null`, thereby implying that an index greater than or equal to the size of the database is to be considered valid.

`Database.getClone()`: The final explicit cast to `List<Rent>` is unnecessary, because it is an upcast, and the upcast happens automatically. The cast to `ArrayList<Rent>` *is* necessary if you really want to use `ArrayList.clone()`, because `List` itself does not declare `clone()` and `Object.clone()` is `protected`, but you can save this trouble if you just use a copy constructor:

```java
return new ArrayList<>(database);
```

I don't know enough about `clone()`, but from what I've read, it's generally considered to be broken, so you should be careful when using it (although [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4592492/8376357) says that it works fine with collections, so in your specific case it might not be a problem).

`Database.add(Rent)` and `Database.set(int, Rent)`. Again, throwing exceptions might be a preferable way to deal with exceptional events.

I don't have time to look at `Menu.java` now, so I'll leave it that for now.

### Update

Continuing this, a remark on your method `Database.getClone()`. After looking through `Menu.java`, it seems that maybe the method [`Collections.unmodifiableList(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-) is what you might want in this case. It doesn't copy the elements from the original `List` but only creates a wrapper for it that rejects all attempts to modify it, but modifications to the original list will still be visible through the returned `List`. Of course, you would have to rename the method since it would not actually clone the database (e.g. `viewDatabase()`).

`Menu.listOverdueRents()`: Here you construct a new `BigDecimal` with a value of `0` instead of using the already existing constant `BigDecimal.ZERO` as you did on two other occasions where you added it to another `BigDecimal` for mysterious reasons, thus unnecessarily creating a new object.

`Menu.getRentObjectFieldsInput()`: [`Scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) will never return `null`, so you don't need to check `scanner.nextLine()` for being `null` (which your code doesn't do anyway, but you seem to think it does).

Next, let's look at these two lines:

```java
rentPrice = scanner.nextDouble();
scanner.nextLine();
```

This consumes the entire line entered by the user into `System.in` but only processes the first token in it, even though a line can contain multiple tokens (the default delimiter of a `Scanner` is whitespace in general, not only line separators). For instance, if the user enters "5 d xx 4.0", `rentPrice` will be set to `5.0` and the rest of the input is ignored. This is confusing. You might want to redesign this to ensure that the whole line is interpreted as a `double`. Also, `Scanner.nextDouble()` will throw an `InputMismatchException` if the next token of the `Scanner` cannot be interpreted as a `double`, and you don't catch this exception, so if the user enters gibberish, your program will crash.

`Menu.editExistingRentObject()`: Declare `counter` inside the `for` loop, since it is not needed outside it (`for (int counter = 0; //etc`), or alternatively, make `Database` implement `Iterable<Rent>` (for instance, by making `iterator()` return `Collections.unmodifiableList(database).iterator()`), so you can use a for-each loop (`for (Rent rent : database)`).

OK, now I see why you wanted `Database.get(int)` to return `null` if the index is not valid. But a better way would be to write a `contains(Rent)` method that returns a `boolean`. Actually, you might consider making `Database` implement `List<Rent>` (or any other subtype of `Collection<Rent>` that seems suitable) directly (you can still store an `ArrayList<Rent>` internally). If you extend `AbstractList`, you don't have to reinvent the wheel but only define the core functionality (but don't extend `ArrayList` as you will be violating its contract by refusing certain elements). That way, it will implement `Iterable<Rent>` as well since `Collection` is a subinterface of `Iterable`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I've fixed everything I could. Gonna update the main post in a minute. I really do want to know your opinion on my fixes and the code overall, of course only if you want and have opportunity. :)

Comment: @Gray K I haven't look at your updates yet, but I've reviewed your original`Menu.java` in the meantime, so I will update my answer with that review for now.

Comment: Please, don't check the updated version yet. I'm gonna make a completely new Database class which extends AbstractList and then update the main post again, for the last time I hope. Thanks!

Comment: @Gray K I'm not sure what just happened, I think I might have inadvertently removed a comment, or maybe not, I don't know. Anyway, it's too late, I've already looked over the updated version :D. So I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Please do not update code to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @SimonForsberg Made another post for the last(I hope) revision of the code. Just again I'm sorry for the inconvenience I've made

Comment: Both question and answer has been rollbacked. The edit history can still be seen. Please avoid updating your answer in response to code edits in the question after your answer.

Comment: @GrayK No problem, now you know. :)

Comment: @Stingy If you still can/want to help, I would be really gladful if you checked out another post(link in the very beginning of the main one). I hope there is not a lot to fix/change/improve. Thanks!