# Movie rent terminal application - revision 3

Tags: java, object-oriented

This is a continuation of the [previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/171424/movie-rent-terminal-application/) (part 3 to be exact). If someone would be interested, the second part can be seen in its history. I've fixed everything I could and rewrote Database2.java from scratch.

**Main.java**

```
package graykas;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Menu.showMainMenu();
    }
}
```

**Movie.java**

```
package graykas;

@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
public final class Movie
{
    private String movieTitle;
    private int rentPriceCents;

    public Movie(String movieTitle, int rentPriceCents)
    {
        setMovieTitle(movieTitle);
        setRentPrice(rentPriceCents);
    }

    public Movie(String movieTitle, double rentPrice)
    {
        setMovieTitle(movieTitle);
        setRentPrice(rentPrice);
    }

    public String getMovieTitle() {   return movieTitle;    }

    private void setMovieTitle(String movieTitle)
    {
        if(movieTitle == null || movieTitle.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Movie title can't be empty or null!");
        this.movieTitle = movieTitle;
    }

    public int getRentPriceCents()
    {
        return rentPriceCents;
    }

    private void setRentPrice(double rentPrice) {   setRentPrice((int)(rentPrice * 100));   }
    private void setRentPrice(int rentPriceCents)
    {
        if(rentPriceCents < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Movie price can't be negative!");
        this.rentPriceCents = rentPriceCents;
    }
}
```

**Rent.java**

```
package graykas;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.util.Objects;

@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
public final class Rent
{
    //Overdue fee per day in cents
    public static final int OVERDUE_FEE_CENTS = 500;

    private String clientName;
    private Movie movie;
    private LocalDate checkoutDate;
    private LocalDate returnDate;

    public Rent(String clientName, Movie movie, String returnDateString)
    {
        setClientName(clientName);
        setMovie(movie);
        setCheckoutDate(LocalDate.now());

        try {   setReturnDate(returnDateString);  }
        catch(NullPointerException | DateTimeParseException ex)
        {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(
                    String.format("Error converting returnDate from String to LocalDate: %s. Using current date instead!", ex.getMessage()));
            setReturnDate(this.checkoutDate);
        }
    }

    public String getClientName() { return clientName;  }
    private void setClientName(String clientName)
    {
        if ((clientName == null || clientName.isEmpty())) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name can't be empty or null!");
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }

    //public Movie getMovie() {   return movie;   }

    /**
     * @param movie - Movie object to set current movie object to
     * @throws NullPointerException if Movie object is null
     */
    private void setMovie(Movie movie)
    {
        this.movie = Objects.requireNonNull(movie, "Movie object can't be null!");
    }

    //public LocalDate getCheckoutDate() {    return checkoutDate;    }
    public void setCheckoutDate(LocalDate checkoutDate)
    {
        this.checkoutDate = checkoutDate;
    }

    //public LocalDate getReturnDate() {  return returnDate;  }
    public void setReturnDate(LocalDate returnDate) {   this.returnDate = returnDate;   }

    /**
     * Converts returnDateString to returnDate LocalDate object
     * @param returnDateString - returnDate represented as String
     * @throws NullPointerException if returnDateString is null
     * @throws DateTimeParseException if returnDateString is not using the following format - yyyy-MM-dd
     */
    public void setReturnDate(String returnDateString)
    {
        this.returnDate = LocalDate.parse(returnDateString);
    }

    /**
     * Returns overdue fee if there is any, i.e. if currentDate > returnDate using formula (currentDate - returnDate) * OVERDUE_FEE
     * @return overdue fee
     */
    public int getOverdueFeeCents()
    {
        if(LocalDate.now().isAfter(returnDate))
            return Period.between(returnDate, LocalDate.now()).getDays() * OVERDUE_FEE_CENTS;
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        /*
        Output example:
            Name: Jack
            Movie title: Harry Potter
            Rent price: $20.99
            Checkout date: 2017-07-28
            Return date: 2017-08-05
            Overdue fee: $0.00
        */
        NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        //noinspection StringBufferReplaceableByString
        StringBuilder strBld = new StringBuilder();
        strBld.append("Name: ").append(clientName).append("\n");
        strBld.append("Movie title: ").append(movie.getMovieTitle()).append("\n");
        strBld.append("Rent price: ").append(currencyFormat.format(movie.getRentPriceCents() / 100.0)).append("\n");
        strBld.append("Checkout date: ").append(checkoutDate).append("\n");
        strBld.append("Return date: ").append(returnDate).append("\n");
        strBld.append("Overdue fee: ").append(currencyFormat.format(getOverdueFeeCents() / 100.0));

        return strBld.toString();
    }
}
```

**Database2.java**

```
package graykas;

import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;

import java.util.*;

@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
public class Database2 extends AbstractList
{
    //Constants for the generator method
    private static final String[] RANDOM_NAMES = {"John", "Felicia", "Ivan", "Boris", "Kristina", "Elena", "Vladimir", "Jane", "Maxim"};
    private static final String[] RANDOM_MOVIE_TITLES = {"Twilight", "Deadpool", "Big Hero 6", "Harry Potter"};
    private static final String[] RANDOM_RETURN_DATES = {"2017-07-21", "2017-07-25", "2017-08-01", "2017-07-01", "2018-07-21"};

    private final ArrayList<Rent> database = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Returns the element at the specified position in this list.
     *
     * @param index index of the element to return
     * @return the element at the specified position in this list
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the index is out of range
     */
    @Override
    @NotNull
    public Rent get(int index) {  return database.get(index); }

    /**
     * Adds an object to the end of the database
     * @param item the object to add
     * @return index of the object
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedReturnValue")
    public int add(Rent item)
    {
        database.add(item);
        return database.lastIndexOf(item);
    }

    /**
     * Replaces an item on the specified index
     * @param index index to replace the item at
     * @param item item to replace to
     */
    public void set(int index, Rent item) { database.set(index, item);  }

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in this list.
     * @return the number of elements in this list
     */
    @Override
    public int size() { return database.size(); }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {  return database.isEmpty();  }

    @Override
    public Iterator iterator() {    return database.iterator(); }

    /**
     * Returns a read-only wrapper for the database
     * @return a read-only wrapper for the database
     */
    @NotNull
    public List<Rent> viewDatabase()
    {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(database);
    }

    /**
     * Inserts a certain amount of random generated Rent objects
     * @param amount amount of Rent objects to generate
     */
    public void generateRandomData(int amount)
    {
        if(amount <= 0) return;

        Random randomNumGen = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            String randomName = RANDOM_NAMES[randomNumGen.nextInt(RANDOM_NAMES.length)],
                    randomMovieTitle = RANDOM_MOVIE_TITLES[randomNumGen.nextInt(RANDOM_MOVIE_TITLES.length)],
                    randomReturnDate = RANDOM_RETURN_DATES[randomNumGen.nextInt(RANDOM_RETURN_DATES.length)];

            int randomMoviePrice = randomNumGen.nextInt(10000);

            Rent generatedRent = new Rent(
                    randomName,
                    new Movie(randomMovieTitle, randomMoviePrice),
                    randomReturnDate);

            this.add(generatedRent);
        }
    }
}
```

**Menu.java**

```
package graykas;

import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;

import java.util.Scanner;

@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
public class Menu
{
    private static final Database2 database = new Database2();

    //Scanner object to get input from the terminal
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     * Shows main menu options
     */
    public static void showMainMenu()
    {
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Available options:");
            System.out.println("1 - List all rents");
            System.out.println("2 - List only overdue rents");
            System.out.println("3 - Add a new rent");
            System.out.println("4 - Edit an existing rent");
            System.out.println("5 - Generate random data");
            System.out.println("0 - Exit");
            System.out.print("Choice -> ");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();

            switch (input)
            {
                case "1":
                    listAllRents();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    listOverdueRents();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    addRentObjectLoop();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    editExistingRentObject();
                    break;
                case "5":
                    database.generateRandomData(5);
                    break;
                case "0":
                    scanner.close();
                    return;
            }
        } while(true);
    }

    /**
     * Lists all the rent objects from the database
     */
    public static void listAllRents()
    {
        //If database is empty -> show "The database is empty" message, else list all the Rent objects' values
        if(!database.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------");

            for(int index = 0; index < database.size(); index++)
            {
                System.out.println("Index: " + index);
                System.out.println(database.get(index));
                System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
            }
        }
        else System.out.println("The database is empty");
    }

    /**
     * Lists all the Rent objects from the database when overdueFee > 0
     */
    private static void listOverdueRents()
    {
        //If database is empty -> show "The database is empty" message, else list all the Rent objects' values with overdueFeeCents > 0
        if(!database.isEmpty())
        {
            //Was at least one Rent object with overdue fee > 0 found?
            boolean found = false;

            for(int index = 0; index < database.size(); index++)
            {
                Rent rent = database.get(index);
                if(rent.getOverdueFeeCents() > 0)
                {
                    if(!found) System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Index: " + index);
                    System.out.println(rent);
                    System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else System.out.println("The database is empty");
    }

    /**
     * Gets Rent objects from user in a loop
     */
    public static void addRentObjectLoop()
    {
        do
        {
            //Gets values for a new Rent object from the user and adds it ti the database
            int index = database.add(getRentObjectFieldsInput());
            System.out.println(String.format("The rent was added at index %s successfully", index));

            //If user doesn't want to continue -> break
            if(!addRentObjectMessage()) break;
        } while(true);
    }

    /**
     * Displays "Do you want to continue?" message
     * @return boolean - true if the user wants to add a new Rent object
     *                  false if does not
     */
    public static boolean addRentObjectMessage()
    {
        System.out.print("Add a new rent? ->");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        return isInputAnAgreement(input);
    }

    /**
     * Gets input for a new Rent object
     * @return Rent object with the data from user
     */
    @NotNull
    public static Rent getRentObjectFieldsInput()
    {
        String clientName;
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Client name -> ");
            clientName = scanner.nextLine();

            if(!clientName.isEmpty()) break;
            System.err.println("Name can't be empty or null! Please, try again");
        } while(true);

        String movieTitle;
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Movie title -> ");
            movieTitle = scanner.nextLine();

            if(!movieTitle.isEmpty()) break;
            System.err.println("Movie title can't be empty or null! Please, try again");
        } while(true);

        double rentPriceDouble;
        {
            String rentPriceString;
            do
            {
                System.out.print("Rent price -> ");
                rentPriceString = scanner.nextLine();

                try
                {
                    rentPriceDouble = Double.parseDouble(rentPriceString);
                    break;
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException ex)
                {
                    System.err.println("Rent price is not a valid number! Please, try again");
                }
            } while(true);
        }

        String returnDate;
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Return date -> ");
            returnDate = scanner.nextLine();

            if(!returnDate.isEmpty()) break;
            System.err.println("Return date can't be empty or null! Please, try again");
        } while(true);


        return new Rent(clientName, new Movie(movieTitle, rentPriceDouble), returnDate);
    }

    /**
     * Edits an object at the specified index by the user
     */
    public static void editExistingRentObject()
    {
        if(database.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("The database is empty");
            return;
        }

        String indexString;
        int index = -1;
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter index of the rent you want to edit -> ");
            indexString = scanner.nextLine();

            try
            {
                index = Integer.parseInt(indexString);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex)
            {
                System.err.println(String.format("Index number could not be parsed: %s", ex.getMessage()));
            }

            if(index > database.size() || index < 0)
            {
                System.err.print("The index is out of database's bounds. Try again? -> ");

                //If the user entered something that can be interpreted as an agreement -> go to the beginning of the loop
                if(isInputAnAgreement(scanner.nextLine())) continue;
            }

            //Break out of the loop if there wasn't an error
            break;
        } while(true);

        System.out.println("Found this rent at the specified index:");
        System.out.println(database.get(index));
        System.out.print("Are you sure you want to edit it? -> ");
        //If the user entered something that can be interpreted as an agreement -> exit the method
        if(!isInputAnAgreement(scanner.nextLine())) return;

        database.set(index, getRentObjectFieldsInput());
    }

    /**
     * Is input by the user an agreement or not?
     * @param input user's input
     * @return true if input = "y" || "yes" || "1"
     *          false otherwise
     */
    private static boolean isInputAnAgreement(String input)
    {
        switch (input.toLowerCase())
        {
            case "y":
            case "yes":
            case "1":
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And just again, my git log, so it could be seen easier what changes exactly I've made:

[image: git log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so let's look at your `Database2.java`. I see you are using `import java.util.*`. I won't reiterate what others who have more experience than I have already explained, so I'll just refer you to [this stackoverflow question on wildcard imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad).

Next, you should extend `AbstractList<Rent>` instead of `AbstractList`. Using `AbstractList<Rent>` provides compile-time safety about the contents of the list, whereas using the raw type `AbstractList` does not.

If you extend `AbstractList<Rent>` instead of `AbstractList`, then your method `add(Rent)` will not compile, because `List.add(E)` returns a `boolean`, not an `int`, and `Database2.add(Rent)` will be interpreted by the compiler as an implementation of `List.add(E)` / an override of `AbstractList.add(E)` because the generic type parameter `E` will then represent `Rent`, thus rendering the method signatures equivalent. In the current state of your code, `add(Rent)` does not override `List.add(E)` because with the list being a raw type, the compiler will read the method declaration `List.add(E)` as `List.add(Object)`, so right now, you have two independent, overloaded methods, one being `List.add(Object)`, implemented by `AbstractList.add(Object)`, and the other being `Database2.add(Rent)`, the first of which throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`, because this is what the default implementation of `AbstractList.add(E)` does.

Also, you seem to have missed the point of creating a custom implementation of `List<Rent>` rather than extending `ArrayList<Rent>`. The reason why I advised against the latter was that your database does not accept `null` elements, whereas an `ArrayList` does, so extending an `ArrayList` and overriding `add(E)` to refuse `null` elements would violate the contract of `ArrayList`. However, your current `Database2` *does* allow `null` elements, because, for some reason, you removed the `null` check from the code. So right now, your `Database2` behaves exactly like an `ArrayList`, which means that it could just as well simply extend `ArrayList` and not override any methods at all, which on the other hand would be pretty pointless, because, seeing as it adds no functionality to an `ArrayList`, you could just create an `ArrayList<Rent>` directly whenever you need to create a new database and make the method `generateRandomData(int)` `static` and return a `List<Rent>` instead of `void`, effectively rendering the class `Database2` a utility class.

So you should make `add(Rent)` check for `null` values and return a `boolean` conforming to the specification of [`List.add(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) so that you don't violate its contract (this means returning `true` if an element is added and throwing an exception when an element is denied, which is explained in `Collection.add(E)`, which is linked to in the documentation of the `return` value of `List.add(E)`).

Furthermore, by making `Database2` extend `AbstractList<Rent>`, you don't have to implement the method `isEmpty()` yourself. You can, but `AbstractList` inherits a default implementation of this method from `AbstractCollection`, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. The [documentation of `AbstractList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) explains exactly which methods you need to implement yourself and which are already implemented by default. Reading it, I see that you don't even have to implement `iterator()`, so I was mistaken about that.

By making `Database2` implement `List<Rent>`, and, in turn, `Iterable<Rent>` (`List` is a subinterface of `Iterable`), you can use a for-each loop in `Menu.listOverdueRents()`.

Also, the method `viewDatabase()` is now redundant, because with `Database2` being a `List` itself, anyone with an instance of `Database2` can simply call `Collections.unmodifiableList(List)` on it. This also makes it obvious that calling `database.getClone()` in your original `Menu.java` was pointless, because you were only accessing it and not passing it to another method where you want to ensure that this method cannot modify your database.

`Menu.editExistingRentObject()`: Declare `indexString` inside the `do` `while` loop, as it is not needed outside it. Also, `index` has to be `>= database.size()`, not `>`.

Finally, making `Database2.generateRandomData(int)` a static method does make sense even when `Database2` is not just a utility class. After all, the generation of random `Rent` objects does not necessarily have to be tied to a specific database. You could instead move the method `generateRandomData(int)` (which, by the way, could be renamed into something like `generateRandomRents`, which would be more descriptive than simply "data"), along with the three arrays containing the random values, into the class `Rent` and make it a `static` factory method for obtaining `Rent` objects. The act of adding these random `Rent`s to a database would then be completely independent of their generation, which would be more in the spirit of the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: I can say from the very beginning that my IDE (IntelliJ) imported java.util.* by itself and I haven't noticed. Gonna take a look at the other things a little bit later, when I come home. Thank you again!